# Display check out detail group by Vendors Name

Tags: php, mysql

When I added (Random added) product to cart by different Vendors.

Ex :

Data Tables.

```
VENDORS TABLE
| vendorid | vendorname |
-------------------------
|     1    |     A      |
|     2    |     B      |
|     3    |     C      |
-------------------------
PRODUCTS TABLE
| productid | productname | postbyvendor(FK) |
----------------------------------------------
|     1     |   Shirt1    |        1         |
|     2     |   Shirt2    |        1         |
|     3     |   Shirt3    |        2         |
|     4     |   Shirt4    |        2         |
|     5     |   Pants1    |        1         |
|     6     |   Pants2    |        3         |
```

Clicked add to Cart for 6 times.

```
1st Add Shirt1 from Vendor A to cart
2nd Add Shirt3 from Vendor B to cart
3rd Add Pants2 from Vendor C to cart
4th Add Shirt2 from Vendor A to cart
5th Add Pants1 from Vendor A to cart
6th Add Shirt4 from Vendor B to cart
```

Cart view displayed like this.

```
<li>Shirt1</li>
<li>Shirt3</li>
<li>Pants2</li>
<li>Shirt2</li>
<li>Pants1</li>
<li>Shirt4</li>
```

I want to display check out detail like this.

```
<li>Vendor Name : A</li>
<li>Shirt1</li>
<li>Shirt2</li>
<li>Pants1</li>
<li>Vendor Name : B</li>
<li>Shirt3</li>
<li>Shirt4</li>
<li>Vendor Name : C</li>
<li>Pants2</li>
```

My query.

```
$statement = $mysqli_conn->prepare("SELECT productname, postbyvendor FROM products_tbl WHERE productname = ? order by postbyvendor asc");
```

Code that i've tried.

```
    foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product){
    $product_name = $product["productname"];
    $vendorsid = $product["postbyvendor"];

    $cart_box = "<li>$vendorsid $product_name</li>";
}
```

Displayed like :

```
<li>1 Shirt1</li>
<li>2 Shirt3</li>
<li>3 Pants2</li>
<li>1 Shirt2</li>
<li>1 Pants1</li>
<li>2 Shirt4</li>
```

Appreciated.

Comment: please post your so far tries..

Comment: Code and my query added.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think if I were to do this, I would make a function to gather the vendors and their items, then loop through them to display, something like:

```
function getVendors()
    {
        foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product) {
            $org[$product["postbyvendor"]][]    =   $product["productname"];
        }

        return (!empty($org))? $org : array();
    }

foreach(getVendors() as $vendor => $prods) {
    echo "<li>{$vendor}</li>";
    echo "<li>".implode("</li><li>",$prods)."</li>";
}
```

Comment: Hi, I want to know how to add more value in your code I've try this.

`function getVendors()
        {
            foreach($_SESSION["products"] as $product) {
                $org[$product["member_display_name"]][]    =   $product["p_name"];
                $org[$product["member_payment"]][]    =   $product["member_display_name"];
            }

            return (!empty($org))? $org : array();
        }

    foreach(getVendors() as $vendor => $prods) {
            echo "<li>Vendor Name : {$vendor} </li>";
            echo "<li>".implode("</li><li>",$prods)."</li>";
    }`