# Select one value from same column with same id

Tags: php, mysql

I want to select product detail and display one image of product from same column.

Ex :

**fm_product TABLE**

```
| p_id | p_name | p_price | p_member_id | << (Added product by member)
-----------------------------------------
| 1    | Shirt  | 600     | 44          |
| 2    | Pants  | 700     | 44          |
| 3    | Shoes  | 800     | 45          |
| 4    | Bag    | 900     | 45          |
```

**fm_product_image TABLE**

```
| img_id | p_id_img | img_name    |
-----------------------------------
| 1      | 1        | Shirt_1.jpg |
| 2      | 1        | Shirt_2.jpg |
| 3      | 1        | Shirt_3.jpg |
| 4      | 2        | Pants_1.jpg |
| 5      | 2        | Pants_2.jpg |
| 6      | 2        | Pants_3.jpg |
| 7      | 3        | Shoes_1.jpg |
| 8      | 3        | Shoes_2.jpg |
| 9      | 4        | Bag_1.jpg   |
| 10     | 4        | Bag_2.jpg   |
```

Member IDs 44 select added product out put should look like this :

```
| p_name | p_price | img_name    |
----------------------------------
| Shirt  | 600     | Shirt_1.jpg |
| Pants  | 700     | Pants_1.jpg |
```

Member IDs 45 select added product out put should look like this :

```
| p_name | p_price | img_name    |
----------------------------------
| Shoes  | 800     | Shoes_1.jpg |
| Bag    | 900     | Bag_1.jpg   |
```

**MY CODE**

```html
$result= mysql_query("select * from fm_product left join fm_product_image on fm_product_image.p_id_img = fm_product.p_id where p_member_id = '$ID' " ) or die (mysql_error());
while ($row= mysql_fetch_array ($result) ){
    $id=$row['p_id'];
    <tr>
    <td style="text-align:center; margin-top:10px; word-break:break-all; width:450px; line-height:100px;">
    <?php if($row['p_id'] != ""): ?>
       <img src="<?php echo $row['img_name']; ?>" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333;">
    <?php else: ?>
       <img src="images/default.png" width="100px" height="100px" style="border:1px solid #333333;">
    <?php endif; ?>
    </td>
    <td style="text-align:center; word-break:break-all; width:300px;"> <?php echo $row ['p_name']; ?></td>
    <td style="text-align:center; word-break:break-all; width:200px;"> <?php echo $row ['p_price']; ?></td>
    </tr>

}
```

Comment: Notice for you: Don't using mysql. Use mysqli or PDO. You can use `DISTINCT`

Comment: Why can't you use pdo?

Comment: @Rasclatt I don't know how to explain that, But can you help me about your answered on my oldest question? [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34714133/display-check-out-detail-group-by-vendors-name)

Comment: This is a simple join. What have you tried so far? Your database functions have been deprecated for five years now. If you can't use PDO, which I find very unlikely, use mysqli.

Comment: So what is not working? Can you explain/show what it is currently doing vs what you want/expect it to do?

Comment: It  worked but it display all of product images. And I want to display for only one of all. Like an example on Member IDs 44 want to display.

Comment: In the name of all that is good and beautiful in this world, just *stop* with developing new PHP code that uses *deprecated* `mysql_` interface functions. It's 2016 already. And using prepared statements with bind placeholders is *not that hard*. Really.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. Thank you guys so much, But I've tried this code and it's worked.

```
SELECT fm_product.p_name, fm_product_image.img_id, fm_product.p_price, fm_product.p_id, fm_product_image.img_1,GROUP_CONCAT(p_id_img) FROM fm_product LEFT JOIN fm_product_image ON fm_product_image.p_id_img = fm_product.p_id WHERE p_member_id = '8' GROUP BY p_id
```